# How can “oneself” as a subject appear after the copula?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

Dictionaries say that the word “oneself” is a *pronoun*, but I’ve just noticed that I can actually put it right *after* the copula, “is,” even if it’s a grammatical subject. Is it because the word “oneself” can also be adverbial? Or if not, could you clarify the grammar in here? I’m a bit confused.

> <sub>From the game “Detroit: Become Human”</sub>
>
> **Elijah Kamski**: Fascinating. CyberLife’s last chance to save humanity, *is itself* a deviant.

[image: “Fascinating. CyberLife’s last chance to save humanity is itself a deviant.”]

Comment: Your question asks about "oneself", but your example includes "itself". I was confused by that.

Comment: The reflexives like "himself", "itself" etc. are always pronouns. They have two main uses: one where they function as complement ("Ed hurt himself"), and an emphatic use where they function as modifier in clause or NP structure  ("Ed designed the house himself" / "Ed himself designed the house").

Comment: @BilliJ I see. Compared to other pronouns, they seem more free of positions just like an adverb, when they’re used for emphasis. They look like a special kind of pronouns.

Comment: Some people use the term 'adverbial' to describe their emphatic use in clause structure. But they are not adverbs, but always pronouns. In your example, (_CyberLife’s last chance to save humanity is itself a deviant_) "itself" has an emphatic use where it functions as modifier (your adverbial) in clause structure, i.e. in the copula VP.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Oh, I was trying to generalize those reflexives. By the “oneself,” I meant all those “-self” words. I’m sorry for the vagueness.

Comment: @BillJ That improves my understanding of English pronouns. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different use. It's used emphatically, specifically to emphasize the unexpectedness or the "quiddity" (it-ness) of the thing.

To understand this last point, here's a typical usage:

> -Who told you Denise was running for mayor?
>
> - She told me herself.

Here, the effect is: "Denise, not some other person! I heard from the person who ought to know best: *the person concerned*."

Similarly:

> They're hosting a gala, and the king himself will be there.

Equivalent to: "Even the *king* will be there (not some representative)!" Implied: How surprising!

So to your example:

> CyberLife’s last chance to save humanity is itself a deviant.

The primary tone here is irony. "You would expect a human to save humanity."

Comment: Neverthless, the reflexives are always pronouns, though their use as modifier in clause structure is sometimes misleadingly termed 'adverbial'.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks -- I've excised the syntactic analysis.